# Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->execute with expression in params

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, pdo, zend-db

I try to execute insert statement with "on duplicate" part. As I know Zend doesn`t support this, so I use simple statement:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO agent(`inn`, `name`, `created`) VALUES(:inn, :name, :created) ON      
DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `inn` = :inn, `name` = :name, `created` = :created";
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($bind);
```

Where **$bind** - is array:

```
array(
  'inn'=>1234567890,
  'name'=>'test user', 
  'created' = new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()')
);
```

If I try this query through phpMyAdmin - all works fine, 
but after script execution the "created" column value is '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.

WTF?

Comment: what happens if you swap the `new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()')` for `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());` ?

Comment: date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()) works... But why doesn`t work Zend_Db_Expr? Or $stmt->execute doesn`t support expr in params at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use an expression as an argument to a placeholder in a prepared statement. It will be interpreted as a string. This has nothing to do with zend framework.

You can either created a formatted date string in php and use that, or use now() in the prepared statement like

```
 VALUES(:inn, :name, NOW())
```

Another solution, if you need to sometimes supply a datetime, and sometimes use NOW(), is using conditionals to check for that specific case

```
 VALUES(:inn, :name, IF(:created = 'NOW()', NOW(), :created))
```